# Check bluetooth status for both IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I really disappointed for finding a way to check if the blue-tooth is on or off for both platforms of IOS and Android in react-native. 
Just, I found some libraries or components that doesn't work properly. Can you introduce me a way or component to find the statues of blue-tooth in react native for IOS and Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in pure React Native to know the status of Bluetooth. You either need to write your own React Native component that will contain some native Android/iOS code or as you said find an existing component that does that for you.

I wrote my own functions to do that but it is part of a bigger project.